# How to query a T-SQL temp table with connectorx (pandas slow)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am using pyodbc to run a query to create a temp table from a bunch of other tables. I then want to pull that whole temp table into pandas, but my pd.read_sql call takes upwards of 15 minutes. I want to try the connectorX library to see if it will speed things up.

For pandas the working way to query the temp table simply looks like:

```
conn = connection("connection string")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""Do a bunch of stuff that ultimately creates one #finalTable""")
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM #finalTable", con=conn)
```

I've been reading the documentation and it appears I can only pass a connection string to the connectorx.read_sql function, and I haven't been able to find a way to pass it an existing connection that carries the temp table I need.

1. Am I able to query the temp table with connectorX? If so how?
2. If not, what would be a faster way to query a large temp table?

Thanks!

Comment: How many rows are we talking? A straight `select` shouldn't normally take that long. Any case, why do you need a temp table anyway?

Comment: 1.5 million rows, 30+ cols, and I actually create around a dozen temp tables and join them together into the final temp table.

Comment: So given the amount of data you are manipulating, how do you know using a different library will speed it up? More likely you have a very slow procedure which needs improvement. Have you actually timed the various parts of the code to work out what is taking so long?

Comment: I have, the part of the procedure creating the temp table takes< 30 seconds. It's only once I try to read that temp table into a dataframe that the slowdown occurs.